# Mystic troubles with iOS deployment target on real devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have a trouble with XCode 5.
Yesterday everything was fine. Today, when I try to run my app on iPhone 5 or iPad Mini I get the following error:

```
iOS deployment target '7.0' for architecture 'armv7s' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '6.1.99' for the iOS 6.1 SDK.
```

Base SDK and Deployment Target are both iOS 7 (Latest version). I have iOS7 on both devices. When I try to launch the app on simulators with iOS7 everything is fine.
I've tried to clean the project, to restart XCode and MAC, looked in project.pbxproj - still can't understand what's up.
So, any help would be very great!

Base SDK:

[image]
Deployment target:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I've solved the problem by deleting iOS 6.1 SDK from XCode completely - I've installed it manually a couple of weeks before. After that the app built with no problems.

Comment: I too had installed the 6.1 SDK to work with an older project, removing it worked like a charm, had to restart Xcode and do a clean build too.

Comment: Side note: You don't have to delete the older SDK. From the rightside of the run/stop button of XCode, You see the targets: Simulator or real device. When you install other SDKs manually, that device list include the same device name 2 times. select the later one and it will build.

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your project to run on iOS 7 but you are building against iOS 6.1 SDK.

You should build against the latest SDK but set the deployment for the lowest version that you would like to support (You have done the opposite here).

In your project build settings make sure you have selected ios 7 as base sdk.

[image]

Comment: Using ios 6.1 sdk and setting deployment target to ios 6, it will run in iOS 7 too but with the iOS 6 look and feel. If you would like to use the new features of iOS 7 you have to use iOS 7 base sdk (and also make lot of UI tweaks so your app is compatible with older iOS versions too).

Comment: I've already changed design and compability for iOS7, because I want the new version to be compatible only with iOS7. So, I don't need ios6 at all.

Comment: As I wrote in the text of the question, Base SDK is already set to iOS7

Comment: This doesn't help also. I've updated the question with some screenshots.

Comment: In the architectures drop down (in the target settings) select "Standard architectures"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I've found the problem myself.

Comment: How did you fixed it?